# PostgreSQL convert month string to start and end dates of month

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to convert e.g. string "201701" to dates '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31' in PostgreSQL?

So for:

```
"201701" get '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31'
"201702" get '2017-02-01' and '2017-02-28'
"201703" get '2017-03-01' and '2017-02-31'
```

etc

Comment: Please see: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question)

Comment: Please add data explaining what you are trying to do here.  Currently, your question does not convey your problem.

Comment: @Tim Done.  Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the `TO_DATE` function, and append the day component using string concatenation, something like this:

```
SELECT
    TO_DATE('201702' || '01', 'YYYYMMDD') AS first,
    (TO_DATE('201702' || '01', 'YYYYMMDD') + INTERVAL '1 month') -
        INTERVAL '1 day' AS last;
```

The above trick just adds `01` to form the first of the month.  For the *last* day of the same month, it first adds one month to the first, to get the first of the next month, then rolls back one day to get the last of the current month.

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Hi @Tim This won't work as the end date differs by month.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer by Tim Biegeleisen works, but here's an alternative.

The `to_date()` function converts a string literal to a date value.

sample usage is : `to_date(text,format);`

`SELECT to_date('201701','YYYYMMDD');`

---

(EDITED)

You can also use date_trunc which is a part of PostgreSQL. It does the same as the above one.

`select date_trunc('month', current_date) , date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '1 month - 1 day';`

[Code Example Live Demo](http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler)